# JavaScript widget must wait for AngularJS variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget, wait

I have some issue with external widget integration on AngularJS platform:

```
<div id="some_widget" param="{{value}}"></div>
<script src="/widget.js"></script>
```

The widget sees by first execution `param = "{{value}}"` as string. Using of timeout would solve the problem, but is not elegant. The using of `ng-if` like this:

```
<script ng-if="value" src="/widget.js"></script>
```

is also not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a watch inside the controller of the view (after inject $scope) to check when the "value" is not undefined (or true, depends on the cases). After the check you can insert the tag script dynamically inside the document and load widget.js.
The code looks like that:

```js
var app = angular.module('awesomeApp', []);
app.controller('awesomeController', function($scope){
    $scope.$watch('value',function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue != undefined) {
          // load script dynamically using any method
          var awesome_script = document.createElement('script');
          awesome_script.setAttribute('src','/widget.js');
          document.head.appendChild(awesome_script);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- import the awesomeController.js file -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="awesomeApp">
    <div  ng-controller="awesomeController">
      <div id="some_widget" param="{{value}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have similar solution, but I create also the div element if value initialized. Looks like the only way.